# Why is let variable accessible within IIFE & var is not?

Tags: javascript, iife

This IIFE code is able to access **count**

```
let count = 0;
(function immediate() {
  if (count === 0) {
    let count = 1;
    console.log(count);
  }
  console.log(count);
})();
```

But why is **count** undefined in this case?

```
var count = 0;
(function immediate() {
  if (count === 0) {
    var count = 1;
    console.log(count);
  }
  console.log(count);
})();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `var` the variable declaration is hoisted, that mean that your code will be rewritted in the following way:

```js
var count = 0;
(function immediate() {
  var count; // decalration of variable hoisted on the function scope
             // and the count variable now is undefined.
  if (count === 0) {
    count = 1;
    console.log(count);
  }
  console.log(count); // just this is printed.
})();
```

As you can se, the variable inside the *if* block is now overriding the global *count*.

The fact that this behaviour is not so obvius is the reason why many suggest to avoid using *var* as we can use *let* and *const* instead, that have a block scope.

**Update**

Thanks to the comment of @t.niese I think is wort to mention another difference between *var* vs *let* and *const*.

Like *var*, *let* and *const* are hoisted, but with this differencese:

1. they have a block scope and **not** a function scope like *var* has
2. they are declared but not initialized to *undefined* like *var*
3. any attempt to access a variable declared with *let* and *const* before it is initialized will result in a *ReferenceError* exception, while accessing an undeclared variable or a hoisted *var* will return just *undefined*.

Comment: Also `let` and `const` are hoisted, but only on a block level, and with a temporal dead zone. `var` is hoisted at a function level and without temporal dead zone.